# Error ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.invoke.MethodType"

Tags: java, android

This error appears in some server returns. I am using the async task for this. I already changed to retrofit but the error remains. So far as I know, I do not use lambda expressions in code.
How can I resolve this error? If necessary, I can put the class codes.

Error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.invoke.MethodType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.sis.app.aten-1/lib/arm,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

Here is my gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "br.com.sis.app.aten"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.0.0.5"
            multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                debuggable false
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
        compile 'com.detectlanguage:detectlanguage:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-translate:v2-rev51-1.23.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        implementation project(':service_aten')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation project(':communication_service')
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The app breaks on this line which is of the asyncTask class:

```
@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        postResultIfNotInvoked(get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    ....
    }
}
```

Gson's methods in which he passes before the break:

```
public static Object parseJsonObjectToObject(JsonObject jsonObject, Object object) throws CommonsException {
    try {
        Gson gson = createGsonObject();

        String nameClass = object.getClass().getCanonicalName().toString();//CRASH!!!!!!
        Object objectParseGson = null;

        objectParseGson = createObject(nameClass);
        objectParseGson = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, object.getClass());

        return objectParseGson;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CommonsException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? It is not in every case that it breaks and other similar projects also run smoothly.

Comment: Please add `multiDexEnabled true` in your defaultConfig inside `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I tried this, it did not work

Comment: I did the editing

Comment: this is because incorrect multidex configuration. How did you handle the multidex, using `MultidexApplication` or `Multidex.install()` or else?

Comment: I only put in gradle, the multidex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved as follows by following the tip in the comments.

I have a class to instantiate the application:

```
public class MyApplicationInstance extends Application {

    private static MyApplicationInstance instanceApplication;

    private String dsChaveAcessoWbs;
    private Tracker mTracker;

    /**
     * Verificação de instancia devido uso da camera
     */
    public MyApplicationInstance() {

        if (instanceApplication == null) {
            instanceApplication = this;
        }
    }

    public static MyApplicationInstance getInstanceApplicationSingleton() {

        return instanceApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
...
}
```

I changed the `Application` to `MultiDexApplication` in this class and it worked.

```
public class MyApplicationInstance extends MultiDexApplication {

    private static MyApplicationInstance instanceApplication;

    private String dsChaveAcessoWbs;
    private Tracker mTracker;

    /**
     * Verificação de instancia devido uso da camera
     */
    public MyApplicationInstance() {

        if (instanceApplication == null) {
            instanceApplication = this;
        }
    }

    public static MyApplicationInstance getInstanceApplicationSingleton() {

        return instanceApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
...
}
```

I followed the google documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html